# What percentage of Americans have Native Indian ancestry?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics

What percentage of americans have native indian ancestry?

I tried to find the answer online and it's difficult to search for.

Comment: Probably unknowable unless you find genetic markers, and do genetic studies on a statistically significant fraction of the population.  And of course you have sub-populations with greater or lesser percentages.

Answer (score 2):

I found some averages from 23andme on [sciencemag](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2014/12/genetic-study-reveals-surprising-ancestry-many-americans). It doesn't state the figures for all americans, although it says that 8 percent of white americans have some native american ancestry, afro-americans have on average 0.8%, and latino have 18% native american ancestry.